# scale a particular variable into zscores is returning a matrix

Tags: r

```
mtcars %>% mutate(mpg_scaled = scale(mpg)) %>% glimpse
Rows: 32
Columns: 12
$ mpg        <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2, 17.8, 16.4, 17.3, 15.2, 10.4, 10.4, 14.7, 32.4, 30.4, 33.9, 21.5, 15.5…
$ cyl        <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 4, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4, 8, 6, 8, 4
$ disp       <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 140.8, 167.6, 167.6, 275.8, 275.8, 275.8, 472.0, 460.0, 440.0, 78.7, 75.7,…
$ hp         <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 180, 180, 205, 215, 230, 66, 52, 65, 97, 150, 150, 245, 175, 66, 91, 113,…
$ drat       <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92, 3.92, 3.07, 3.07, 3.07, 2.93, 3.00, 3.23, 4.08, 4.93, 4.22, 3.70, 2.76…
$ wt         <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.150, 3.440, 3.440, 4.070, 3.730, 3.780, 5.250, 5.424, 5.345, 2.200, 1.61…
$ qsec       <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22.90, 18.30, 18.90, 17.40, 17.60, 18.00, 17.98, 17.82, 17.42, 19.47, 18.5…
$ vs         <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1
$ am         <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
$ gear       <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 4
$ carb       <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2, 4, 6, 8, 2
$ mpg_scaled <dbl[,1]> <matrix[32 x 1]>
```

Expected the new field 'mpg_scaled' to be just a regular dbl like the rest but why does it say it's a matrix <matrix[32 x 1]>?

If I look at the head it appears like a regular numeric field:

```
mtcars %>% mutate(mpg_scaled = scale(mpg)) %>% head
   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb mpg_scaled
1 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4  0.1508848
2 21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4  0.1508848
3 22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1  0.4495434
4 21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1  0.2172534
5 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2 -0.2307345
6 18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1 -0.3302874
```

What's happening here? What is mpg_scaled? How can I make it a 'regular' field like the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just index into the resulting matrix to return a vector. `base::scale`'s documentation says that its input `x` is "a numeric matrix(like object)", and its output value is "the centered, scaled matrix". So the function is built to work on matrix columns, but will accept vector input and interpret it as a one column matrix.

```r
library(tidyverse)
mtcars %>% mutate(mpg_scaled = scale(mpg)[,1]) %>% glimpse
#> Rows: 32
#> Columns: 12
#> $ mpg        <dbl> 21.0, 21.0, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, 18.1, 14.3, 24.4, 22.8, 19.2…
#> $ cyl        <dbl> 6, 6, 4, 6, 8, 6, 8, 4, 4, 6, 6, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 4, 4, 4…
#> $ disp       <dbl> 160.0, 160.0, 108.0, 258.0, 360.0, 225.0, 360.0, 146.7, 14…
#> $ hp         <dbl> 110, 110, 93, 110, 175, 105, 245, 62, 95, 123, 123, 180, 1…
#> $ drat       <dbl> 3.90, 3.90, 3.85, 3.08, 3.15, 2.76, 3.21, 3.69, 3.92, 3.92…
#> $ wt         <dbl> 2.620, 2.875, 2.320, 3.215, 3.440, 3.460, 3.570, 3.190, 3.…
#> $ qsec       <dbl> 16.46, 17.02, 18.61, 19.44, 17.02, 20.22, 15.84, 20.00, 22…
#> $ vs         <dbl> 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1…
#> $ am         <dbl> 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1…
#> $ gear       <dbl> 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4…
#> $ carb       <dbl> 4, 4, 1, 1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 1, 2, 1…
#> $ mpg_scaled <dbl> 0.1508848, 0.1508848, 0.4495434, 0.2172534, -0.2307345, -0…
```

<sup>Created on 2020-08-03 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

We could also remove the `dim` attributes by coercing to a `vector` with `as.vector` on the `matrix`

```
library(dplyr)
mtcars %>% 
     mutate(mpg_scaled = as.vector(scale(mpg)))
```

Comment: `drop()` also works, and might (?) be more descriptive